# What is a coordinate function $x^i$ of a manifold, given a chart $(U,x)$?

Tags: differential-topology

I am trying to understand the notes here: http://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/cotangent-vectors-differentials-and-the-cotangent-bundle/.

Specifically, this sentence: If we have local coordinates $(U,x)$ at $p$, then each coordinate function $x^i$ is a smooth function...

**Question:** what is the smooth function $x^i$?

My understanding is that if we have a manifold $M$, a point $p \in M$, and a chart or "local coordinate" $(U,x)$ at $p$, then a smooth function $f$ is a map from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Am I right that $x^i: M \to \mathbb{R}^n$ too, but it outputs the $i$-th standard basis vector? i.e. $x^i(p) = e_i$?

Comment: The $x^i$s are explicitly defined on page 34 here: http://www.math.binghamton.edu/paul/601-S06/AS3.pdf.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think if $x: M \mapsto \mathbb R^n$ such that $x(p)= q$, then $x^i(p) = q^i$.  The coordinate *function* $x^i$ returns the $i$th coordinate of the vector $q$.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense. I made a mistake with $f$. It is suppose to be $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$. So, $x^i(p) = q_i$ is exactly a function that like. +1 and accepted