# Why the gamma factors $\Gamma_{k l}^{j}$ are zero in flat submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics

> **Axiom 2.1**. The Newtonian spacetime is characterized geometrically by a pentuple $\mathbb{N}=\langle N, D, \Omega, V, \hat{h}\rangle$,
> where
>
> 1. $N$ is a paracompact, connected, oriented and noncompact fourdimensional smooth manifold.
> 2. $D$ is a linear connection on $N$ such that its tensors of torsion and curvature satisfy $$ T[D]=0 \quad \text { and } \quad R[D]=0 $$
> 3. $\Omega \in \sec \left(T^{*} N\right), \Omega \neq 0$, is a differentiable 1 -form field on $N$ such that $$ D \Omega=0 $$
> 4. $V \in \sec (T N)$ is a differentiable vector field on $N$ such that $\Omega(V)=1$
> 5. $\hat{h} \in T_{0}^{2} N$ is a two-covariant, symmetric, and differentiable tensor field on $N$ such that for every $p \in N$ (a)
>    $\hat{h}_{p}\left(u_{p}, v_{p}\right)=0 \forall u_{p} \in T_{p} N \Leftrightarrow v_{p}=k V_{p}, k \in \mathbb{R}$
>    (b)
>    $\hat{h}_{p}\left(u_{p}, u_{p}\right)>0 \forall u_{p} \in T_{p} N$ (c)
>    $\left.D \hat{h}\right|_{p}=0$
>
> **Definition 2.2**. Any function $t: N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for which $\Omega_{p}=a d t_{p} \neq 0$ for all $p \in N, a \in \mathbb{R}, a>0$
> , is called an (admissible) time function for
> $\mathbb{N}$. If $a=1$, the function $t$ is also said to be
> normalized. For each admissible time function $t: N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
> , the number $t(p) \in \mathbb{R}$ is called time (relative
> to $t)$ of the event $p \in N$ and given two events $p, q \in N$, the
> number $|t(q)-t(p)|$ is called temporal interval (relative to $t$ )
> between $p$ and $q$
>
> Two events $p, q \in N$ are said to be simultaneous if and only if
> $t(p)=t(q)$. For each $p \in N$, the set $$ S_{p}=\{q \in N,t(q)=t(p)\} $$
> of all events simultaneous with the event $p$ is called
> absolute simultaneity space at $p .\left(\right.$
> Obviously,$S_{q}=S_{p}$ if $\left.t(p)=t(q) .\right)$
>
> **Proposition 2.4.** For each $p \in N$ the set $S_{p}$ is a flat three-dimensional submanifold of $N$
>
> **Definition 3.1**. A reference frame on $\mathbb{N}$ is characterized by a futurepointing timelike vector field $E \in \sec (T \mathscr{U}),\mathscr{U} \subseteq N$
> , such that $$ \Omega_{p}\left(E_{p}\right)=1$$
>
> **Definition 3.3**. We say that $E$ is inertial if and only if $$ D E=0 $$ at all points of $\mathscr{U}$.
>
> **Definition 3.22.** A (proper) moving frame on $\mathbb{N}$, defined in $\mathscr{U} \subset N$, is a quadruple
> $\left\langle e_{\mu}\right\rangle=\left\langle e_{0}, e_{1}, e_{2},e_{3}\right\rangle, e_{\mu} \in \sec (T \mathscr{U}), \mu=0,1,2,3$
> , of
> linearly independent differentiable vector fields on
> $\mathscr{U} \subset N$ such that, at each $p \in \mathscr{U}$,
>
> 1. $\Omega_{p}\left(e_{0}\right)=1$,
> 2. $\Omega_{p}\left(e_{k}\right)=0, k=1,2,3$.  where $\Omega$ is a one form. The dual frame is
>    $\left\langle\theta^{\mu}\right\rangle=\left\langle \theta^{0}=\Omega, \theta^{1}, \theta^{2}, \theta^{3}\right\rangle$
>
> **Definition 3.25.** A moving frame $\left\langle e_{\mu}\right\rangle$ on $\mathscr{U} \subset N$ will be called
> **coordinate** if and only if, at each $p \in \mathscr{U}$, $$ \left.\mathscr{L}_{e_{\mu}} e_{v}\right|_{p}=0 $$ where $\mathscr{L}$
> stands for the Lie derivative.
>
> **Proposition 3.33.** A moving frame $\left\langle e_{\mu}\right\rangle$ on $\mathbb{N}$, defined in $\mathbb{U} \subset N$
> , is coordinate if and only if $$ \Gamma_{\mu v}^{\rho}=\Gamma_{v\mu}^{\rho} $$
>
> **Definition 3.34.** Let $E \in \sec (T \mathscr{}), \mathbb{U} \subseteq N$, be a reference frame field. A moving frame $\left\langle e_{\mu}\right\rangle$
> on $\mathbb{N}$, defined in $\mathscr{U} \subset \mathbb{N}$
> will be said to be naturally adapted to $E$ in
> $\mathscr{U}$ if and only if $$ e_{0 p}=E_{p} $$
> **Proposition 3.36.** A moving frame $\left\langle e_{\mu}\right\rangle$ naturally adapted to an inertial reference frame
> $I \in \sec (T \mathscr{U}), \mathscr{U} \subseteq N$
> is coordinate if and only if
> $$ \Gamma_{\mu v}^{\rho}=0 $$ in all points of $\mathscr{U}$, where
> $\Gamma_{\mu v}^{\rho}=\theta^{\rho}\left(D_{e_{\mu}} e_{v}\right)$

> **Proof:** If $\Gamma_{\mu v}^{\rho}=0$ in $\mathscr{U}$, then obviously
> $\left\langle e_{\mu}\right\rangle$ is coordinate, since in this case
> $c_{\mu v}^{\rho}=\Gamma_{\mu v}^{\rho}-\Gamma_{v \mu}^{\rho}=0$ in
> $\mathscr{U}$.
>
> Conversely, if $\left\langle e_{\mu}\right\rangle$ is coordinate, we
> have $\Gamma_{\mu v}^{\rho}=\Gamma_{v \mu}^{\rho}$ in $\mathscr{U}$
> and therefore, taking into account that $e_{0}=I \Rightarrow D_{c_{\mu}} e_{0}=D_{e_{\mu}} I=0$
> in $\mathscr{U}$, we have
> $$\Gamma_{\mu 0}^{p}=\Gamma_{0 \mu}^{\rho}=0 $$ in $\mathscr{U} .$ in
> $\mathscr{U}$.  This concludes our proof, since the components
> $\Gamma_{k l}^{0}$ and $\Gamma_{k l}^{j}$ will be always null in
> $\mathbb{U}$, the first because $\Omega\left(e_{l}\right)=0$ and the
> other because the spacelike submanifolds of $N$ are flat.

The text in blockquote  is from  in this article [The mathematical structure of Newtonian spacetime: Classical dynamics and gravitation](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02080568) .

I am not seeing why gamma factors $\Gamma_{k l}^{j}$ in preposition 3.36 are zero. Could anyone explain  me why?

A contra example would be the basis associate to the spherical coordinates $(t,r,\theta,\phi)$ , $e_0=\frac{\partial}{\partial t},e_1=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}, e_2=\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta},e_3=\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$. They satisfy the condition above but not all the coefficient $\Gamma$ are zero.

Comment: Not sure I understand all your notation, but the geometric idea is that on a flat manifold, an orthonormal frame at one point induces via parallel transport a local _coordinate_ frame (parallel transport is locally path-independent on a flat manifold), whose Christoffel vanish for the same reason the Christoffel symbols of the standard Euclidean frame vanish.

Comment: But that doesn't seem to be what they're doing, @AndrewD.Hwang. Despite the notation, the $e_i$ are just coordinate vector fields. Indeed, even in a flat space (as opposed to the sphere) you can have nonzero Christoffel symbols (use polar coordinates on the plane). As it stands, the claim seems to be plain wrong. Of course, one can *choose* an appropriate coordinate system (hence $e_i$) to make it be true because we are given that $N$ is flat, hence locally isometric to Euclidean space.

Comment: I will edit my question

Comment: I dont believe the counterexample of spherical coordinates applies given the linked paper's definition of coordinates (cf. observations 2.37, 3.26).

Comment: @mxnoqwerty I am not seeing why observations 2.37, 3.26 implies that the polar coordinates does not   apply to the definition. Note that inertial reference is only referring to $e_0$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720328/what-is-a-coordinate-function-xi-of-a-manifold-given-a-chart-u-x

Comment: @mxnoqwerty what do you mean by the link?

Comment: @TedShifrin: Not sure I follow...? Certainly general coordinate fields in flat space do not yield vanishing $\Gamma_{jk}^{i}$, but Christoffel symbols for a frame vanish iff the fields are covariantly constant, i.e. (b/c we're in flat space), are induced by local parallel transport, right? <> Either way, the question has been substantially expanded, and the "inertial" condition looks related to fields being covariantly constant, but there are still notational issues I don't understand. (A number of stray $>$ symbols, maybe also an index convention about space versus spacetime indices.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I did not find any place where the frame is required to be covariantly constant. Have you?

Comment: @Max: My current best surmise of the authors' notation and terminology is, an _inertial_ frame is covariantly constant (albeit not by definition; this must be deduced from covariant constancy of the "time gauge" $E$). That appears to be the content of Proposition 3.36, and seems consistent with framing Newtonian mechanics in differential-geometric terms. But if I felt I understood in detail, I'd answer instead of commenting.